# auto submit dropdown list in php

Tags: php, forms

I want to create a dropdown list in a form and be able to submit/process it without pressing the submit button. I have

```
$cquery = 'SELECT * FROM tcat ORDER BY id ASC';
$cresult = mysql_query($cquery, $connection);
if(!$cresult){echo 'no result' . mysql_error();}
while($crow = mysql_fetch_array($cresult))
{echo $crow['cat'] . '</option><option>';}
?>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to make the default that is shown a different value aside the first or the last

Comment: I'm assuming you want to auto-submit when the dropdown changes? You could use javascript & add `onchange="this.form.submit()"` to your select element. You can't do that with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even simpler, this should work too!

```
<select onchange="submit();">
  <options ... >
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

To submit a form without having the user press a submit button, you can use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
```

To set a default selected option, you can do this:

```
<option selected="selected">Category Name</option>
```

Note that PHP will not auto-submit a form for you as it is a server-side language.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use html and javascript and change your script to generate them accordingly:

```
<select name="aName" onChange="document.getElementById('yourFormId').submit();">
...
</select>
```